# Can i import android studio project build on windows to mac os?

Tags: android, windows, macos

I have android project on my windows os and I want to open it on my mac os,
but there is an error

> Error: The resource name shouldn't be empty

and when I click run it is alert 3 Virtual device like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glnUm.png) and all of them doesn't work.

I hope you help me friends.

Comment: Use Github. Create an account with Github, on your windows computer, push your project to github.... then on your mac, clone the project and open in android studio

Answer (score 0):

No, you have no problem to switch your project from Windows to MacOS.

Your problem probably depends from the different Android studio version.

Check in your project if there are new files created or without extension or you can try to use the same version of Android studio.

Comment: Version on windows is android studio 3.1.3 and 3.1.4 on mac os what i have to do ?

Comment: I check the gradle is 4.4 in both projects !